# Projective plane as a subcomplex of a 2-dimensional CW complex homotopy equivalent to $S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, projective-space, cw-complexes

Note that we can embed $\Bbb RP^2$ into a topological space that is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$. This is because $\Bbb RP^2$ embeds in $\Bbb R^n$ for some large $n$ (which is true for every smooth manifold), and so $\Bbb RP^2$ embeds in $S^2\times \Bbb R^n$ which is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$.

My question is, can we embed $\Bbb RP^2$ as a subcomplex of a 2-dimensional cell complex that is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$? This means that regarding $\Bbb RP^2$ as a (2-dimensional) cell complex, we can attach more 0,1,2-cells to $\Bbb RP^2$ to get a space homotopy equivalent to $S^2$. I can't see whether this is true or not. Any hints?

Comment: The quotient must have the homology of $S^2$, with the quotient map inducing multiplication by $2$ on $H_2$.

Comment: In the other direction, $C(\mathbb{R}P^2) \vee S^2$ is a $3$-dimensional complex that contains $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as a subcomplex and is equivalent to $S^2$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez If $X$ is such a complex then the quotient $X/\mathbb{R}P^2$ is a $2$-dimensional complex and the pair $(X, \mathbb{R}P^2)$ has the same homology as $(X/\mathbb{R}P^2, *)$ by the quotient map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there exists such a complex.

**Hint:** Attach a $2$-cell to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ via a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}P^1 \cong S^1 = \partial D^2$. Equivalently, this can also be described as the mapping cone of the inclusion $\mathbb{R}P^1 \subset \mathbb{R}P^2$.

More generally, the mapping cone of the inclusion $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}P^n$ is a complex of dimension $n$ which is homotopy equivalent to $S^n$ and contains $\mathbb{R}P^n$ as a subcomplex.